# SVN Web-dav isn't asking for authenication

Tags: security, svn, webdav

We are running a Ubuntu 9.10 server with Web-Dav to host an SVN repository. Here's my dav_svn.conf settings for it:

```
<Location /svn/myrepo>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /home/svn/myrepo
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Our Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
        <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
                Require valid-user
        </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

I can access it here:

```
http://myserver.com/svn/myrepo
```

But it isn't asking for any type of authentication. Am I missing something here? `/etc/subversion/passwd` exists and is populated with usernames and password hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using LimtExcept this way you are limiting access to the repository *except for* the GET, PROPFIND, OPTIONS and REPORT methods.

That means read-only access to the repository is permitted but authentication is required when commiting code.

Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Jakobud: If you remove the <LimitExcept> block around Require valid user, you should always have to authenticate.